# Few lines from app.py script I don't understand

Tags: python, html, class, render, web.py

So I understand here that python is assigning the `render` variable to web.template.render, but I don't really get what it's doing in english. My templates directory is being "called" (is this the right word?) and the `layout.html` is used in some way. I've been trying to break the code and it still works without this line though. I've been instructed to use this and don't understand it.

```
render = web.template.render('templates/', base="layout")
```

The following class makes sense to me to this extent: an object assigned to it will return `hello_form.html` and because of the second function (method?) it will allow a user to input things into a prompt and return those values. I don't understand very deeply what the `form` variable line or the `return` line are doing though. Any help or quick translations will help me greatly, thanks!

```
class Index(object):
    def GET(self):
        return render.hello_form()

    def POST(self):
        form = web.input(name = "what", greet = "no response?")
        greeting = "%s, %s" % (form.greet, form.name)
        return render.index(greeting = greeting)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong but your confusion is the `name = "what"` type syntax?  This just says that the function, in this case `web.input` takes a parameter called `name` and you are assigning it directly to `"what"`.  Same with `render.index(greeting = greeting)`, it takes a parameter `greeting` to which you assign the value of the local variable `greeting` which was evaluated in the line above the `return` statement.

So without looking at the method, I would say there is no guarantee that `return render.index(greeting)` is the same as `render.index(greeting = greeting)`.   Take for example this snippet of code taken from [here](http://www.penzilla.net/tutorials/python/functions/), but without the infinite loop I just noticed:

```
# Default Values
def multiprint(n=5, txt=""):
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        print txt
        i++
```

You could then call this function this way:

```
>>> multiprint()






>>> multiprint(1)


>>> multiprint(1,"hi")
hi

>>> multiprint(txt="hi")
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
```

Where in the last line we did not specify `n`, the first parameter, but did specify `txt`.  I also agree with you that `greeting = greeting` is confusing.  It seems like a cute little trick, but I don't much care for it.  The parameter name is `greeting`, like `txt` in our example, and the local variable is `greeting`.  Personally, I would have named the local variable something else and then had, `render.index(greeting = myGreetingText)` or something like that.

Comment: Is `return render.index(greeting)` different than `return render.index(greeting = greeting)`? Are you saying that that the first `greeting` is the parameter taken, but doing `= greeting` makes the parameter refer to the local variable `greeting`? If this is the case, it'd be much less confusing to type `return render.index(greetparam = greeting)` or something like that.